# Cocoa, can't make window appear programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am having a problem making a window appear programmatically.....

I have created the window in the interface builder and I have a window controller class

I have and `IBOutlet NSWindow mywindow` in the controller class that is bound to the window (via interface builder).

I have tried calling `[mywindow display]` and `[mywindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]`  but neither display the window.

If in the interface builder I set 'Visible at Launch', the window is visible when the application launches, but now I can't hide it... calling `[mywindow close]` does nothing.

I think I have missed something pretty basic here but can't work out what.

Comment: have you set a break point and made sure mywindow is not nil at that point?  Just want to make sure there's not an issue with the XIB bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're calling this code from within the IB window controller instance and not from a programmatically created instance? Try with `NSLog(@"%@",myWindow);` to check whether `myWindow` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 1) your window exists, 2) that the connection is made in IB, and 3) the coordinates of the window aren't off-screen.

Comment: With the breakpoint set, the mywindow object shows as (NSWindow \*) 0x0.... not sure if this means it hasn't been initialised properly? ... btw, in IB, the outlets *do* show up as correctly linked

Comment: Please post the code that you're using to instantiate your window controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that **Release When Closed** check box for mywindow is unchecked in attribute inspector